# Any example of the Schur decomposition?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

I have been searching the internet for 2 hours and literally found no example of the **Schur decomposition**, which says that in some conditions on matrix $A$ we can write it as:

$$A = Q T Q^H$$

where $T$ is upper triangular and $Q$ is unitary.

May someone give and example of such a matrix with its full Schur decomposition.

Comment: You can **always** write a complex matrix in this form. Take any upper triangular matrix as an example. If this does not suffice, pick your favourite othogonal $Q$ and conjugate for an example.

Comment: Maybe you were searching the internet for a Schur thing?

Comment: @copper.hat I have asked for specific example... plus this isn't true for any matrix, I didn't write what are the requirements since they are known

Comment: Can you give me an example of a square matrix that does not have a Schur decomposition?

Comment: I gave you a recipe for creating examples.